# Next without For error when there is a for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am receiving a 'Next without For' on one of my for each loops when there is a `For each` statement. The error is highlighting the for loop for `cell`

```
'   Find and delete

Dim clear As Range

For Each clear In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If clear.Value = "TRANS_DATE" Then clear.Cells.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
Next clear

Dim total As Range
For Each total In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If total.Value = "Total Amount:" Then total.Cells.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
Next total

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow And cell.Font.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
    cell.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
Next cell

Dim error As Range
For Each error In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If error.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow Then
    error.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp

End If
Next
```

Any suggestions to what might be wrong would be appreciated!

Comment: Your 3rd loop is missing an `End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow And cell.Font.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        cell.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    -------- need and END if here ---------
Next cell
```

Whole code:

```
Dim clear As Range

For Each clear In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If clear.Value = "TRANS_DATE" Then clear.Cells.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
Next clear

Dim total As Range
For Each total In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If total.Value = "Total Amount:" Then total.Cells.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
Next total

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow And cell.Font.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
       cell.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End If <- added this
Next cell

Dim error As Range
For Each error In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If error.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow Then
        error.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp

    End If
Next
```

I would always recommend strict rules on indenting as you would see this more easily. A new line on the If means you need the End If.

Comment: assuming it isn't SO wrapping your line of code... that is

Comment: Thanks. I seem to be having an issue where VBA is not detecting the cells that meet both criteria in my 'if cell.interior.color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow And cell.Font.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then...' and it is skipping over the cells that have both a yellow highlight and red font color. Checked to make sure the colors were the same RGB but it is still not deleting them.. any suggestions?

Comment: If it does not hit the cell.Delete line, then one of the two if statements guarding it will be false. I would store the actual values into a variable and then inspect what they are. Try and work out if it is the Yellow, or Red (or both) which is not matching. Maybe record new macro, just set a cell to yellow and text red, and then compare what it generates in the macro code for those values. I don't think it will create your RGB(...) bit.